# solr: tree-like structure DIH

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I'm trying to denormalize a tree-like structure into solr.

I mean, into my relational database I've this:

```
                                      +------------+
                                      |            |
+--------------+             +--------v--------+   |
|              |             |                 |   |
|   Employee   +-----------> |   Department    +---+
|              |             |                 |
+--------------+             +-----------------+
```

Any department can have any subdepartment.

Are there any tips or tricks in order to denormalize this kind of relationships into solr?

I bit more of details.

Currently, I've created an index storing all denormalized employees.

Something like:

```
employee_id, employee_name, department_id, depatment_name
```

However, I need to make searches like:

```
  Department (210)
    Deparment1 (100)
      Department-1.2 (50)
      Department-1.3 (50)
    Department2 (110)
      Department-2.2 (40)
      Department-2.3 (70)
```

The problem using my approach employees only have the current department, department tree associated is not available...

Any ideas about how to get it?

I hope I've explained so well...

Comment: You can define a custom field with the path hierarchy tokenizer: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/tokenizers.html#Tokenizers-PathHierarchyTokenizer - make sure your SQL includes the whole path, and Solr will handle it so you can generate the facets on the other side from each token (and in your frontend you only display the last part of the path)

Comment: If you have never used the ancestor_path and descendent_path fields in Solr this blog might help: https://library.brown.edu/DigitalTechnologies/searching-for-hierarchical-data-in-solr/

Comment: Is there any issue about using root slash? In your example you are using `db/rel/mysql` without root `/`. What about using `/db/rel/mysql`?